# click once deploying databases

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

We have a main application and a client application. we need to syncronize data between this two applications because the client application will have a local database and any changes will need to be sent back to the main application the syncronize the db.

Now the issue is when we have updates to the database and need to publish them to the client application. we don't want to overwrite the current database they have. I believe we need to some how check first to see if they have run it for the first time and deploy the database if they already have it just run updates. What would be the easiest way to deploy updates to the database using click once. would we just have scripts contained in a folder and when we plublish the update the application checks in the folder if the scripts exists and if so execute them . any ideas thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827749/deploying-databases)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Deploying Databases][1]. I already posted an answer there. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827749/deploying-databases