# Deploying Databases

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

we have a client application with a local database. Once in a while we need to provide updates to the database ranging from changing a column , adding a column etc etc.  We want to check if the application is run for the first time deploy the database. If not, check for updates.  What would be the easiest way to deploy database updates through click once.
Could this be deploying the scripts to a folder and having the local app check and run?

Answer (score 0):

use [entity framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) with [automatic migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx) turned on, and make sure all changes to the database are handled via EF migration.

when you decide to change server app - you do the following:

1. Change main app
2. Change client app schema
3. Push new build setting version to be current - this way when user
   starts client app, it will not work unless latest version is
   downloaded and run
4. When  version is downloaded, run EF migration scripts on start.

Comment: I should explain a bit more. There are two applications. one is the main application on the network that already uses entity framework. Then there is another application that has a local database because it needs to work offline for clients outside the network.  When we need to make changes to their database (client) what would be the easiest way to deploy changes to their DB. we will be communicating via wcf.

Comment: still not clear - publish updates to the app with local DB? then everything works as I described - let that app use EF to manage DB schema, and by publishing an update, you will promote desired changes to the app via automatic migrations

Comment: The client application will use entity frame work to communication with their database. we don't want to replace the whole database on their end everytime we publish an update, the issue is the database is a local db on their computer. So when we need to send out updates to all the clients , we need to make changes to everyones database, its not on a server. so we want to use click once to include "scripts" and then once they have it on their end, run the scripts.

Comment: ok, so when the client already has the database and they are running an update. run EF migration scripts, how does that work exactly. Say if i have a script "alter table, alter column blah blah" needs to be run on their local db. how can i get it to run at start up exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you include the scripts for updating the database. Include a version number in the script(s). Also store a version number in the database. Have the app check to see if there are scripts included. You can use some kind of template name to check for them with a wildcard, or put them in a resource string. If there are scripts, compare the version number with the one in the database to see if you need to execute the scripts, and if so, do so and then update the version in the database.

Another tip -- please don't store your data in the DataDirectory and rely on ClickOnce to carry it forward. It's dangerous. Check out [this article](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/where-do-i-put-my-data-to-keep-it-safe-from-clickonce-updates/) telling you how to handle data so it doesn't get mucked up by ClickOnce updates.